# CLick event listener written in typescript unbinds on its own

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

Pretty new to Typescript, but have some experience with JavaScript. Couldn't figure out why this was behaving like this.
Attached an event listener to a button like

```
document.querySelector("#sr").addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log(1);
        new GetApi().entered_name();
    });
```

It works fine the first time, but not afterwards. But when i remove the `new GetApi().entered_name()`, it works fine all times.

Here is the function

```
entered_name()
     {
       console.log(document.getElementById("fname").value);
        return fetch("https://localhost:5001/api?search="+document.getElementById("fname").value)
            .then(Response=>Response.json())
            .then(data=>{
         console.log(data[0]);
         let res =new UserData(data[0]);
         console.log(res);
         let obj = new Display1();
         obj.showUserData(res);  


       }).catch(err=>console.log(err));
     }
```

And here is the `showUserData()`

```
export class Display1
{
    showUserData(obj : UserData){
    {
        document.body.innerHTML += "Props in HTML tags";
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `showUserData` method resets DOM by adding string to inner html. So after that operation literally element `#sr` is re-created and all events should be bound again for it.
Try to use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). Something like this:

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "Props in HTML tags");
```